# SQL Server STRING_SPLIT()

Tags: sql, sql-server, split, cross-apply

I'm trying to use this function on a column but it seems that that is not allowed:

If I use

```
SELECT * 
FROM STRING_SPLIT('John,Jeremy,Jack', ',')
```

I get the values 'John', 'Jeremy and 'Jack'

Whilst if I use:

```
SELECT * 
FROM STRING_SPLIT(Obs, ' ')
```

(`Obs` is text)

or

```
SELECT * 
FROM STRING_SPLIT(appointments notes, ' ')
```

I get the error message:

> Argument data type void type is invalid for argument 1 of string_split function

I even tried:

```
SELECT * 
FROM STRING_SPLIT(select obs from log, '-')
```

which results in this error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
> Incorrect syntax near '-'

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Please share sample data from log table.

Comment: Post queries that actually reproduce a problem. What are you trying to do? The first query works perfectly and returns 3 rows. The second is identical to the first. Both work on a *string*, not a column. In the third, what is `appointments.notes` ??? The fourth makes no sense.

Comment: Are you trying to split the values of another table's column? Use CROSS APPLY. You need to specify the root table in `FROM`. You can't apply a function that returns a table in `FROM`. There are no nested results sets in SQL

Comment: If you check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#b-split-comma-separated-value-string-in-a-column) it shows you how to use it. Reading the documentation should be one of your first calls when you don't know how to use something in a language.

Answer (score 3):

When you are using string_split() on a column of a table you can try it with cross apply.

Here goes your query:

```
select value from 
 log cross apply STRING_SPLIT(obs,',')
```

DB-Fiddle
your query:

```
 create table log(Obs varchar(500));
 insert into log values('ohn,Jeremy,Jack');
```

Your query:

```
 select value from 
 log cross apply STRING_SPLIT(obs,',')
```

Output:

| value |
| --- |
| ohn |
| Jeremy |
| Jack |

example:

```
 CREATE TABLE contacts (
     id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
     first_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
     last_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
     phones VARCHAR(500)
 );

 INSERT INTO 
     contacts(first_name, last_name, phones)
 VALUES
     ('John','Doe','(408)-123-3456,(408)-123-3457'),
     ('Jane','Doe','(408)-987-4321,(408)-987-4322,(408)-987-4323');
```

Query:

```
 SELECT 
     first_name, 
     last_name,
     value phone
 FROM 
     contacts
     CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(phones, ',');
```

Output:

| first_name | last_name | phone |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | Doe | (408)-123-3456 |
| John | Doe | (408)-123-3457 |
| Jane | Doe | (408)-987-4321 |
| Jane | Doe | (408)-987-4322 |
| Jane | Doe | (408)-987-4323 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=786353c85faf945ac8e4a86c044b64f9)*

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the help, I've tried your suggestions but keep getting the same errors.

Here is a 2 record sample from the log column:

```
Obs 
ID:786988|Patient_ID:320165|Staff_ID:PF|Date:05/06/2021 13:00:24|DiaryTemplates_ID:244799|Notes:Relatório 786988|Access:1|EventID:5|Status:4|Staff_ID_Writer:PES|Staff_ID_Signature:0|StatusReason:|StatusObs:|DateReceived:05/06/2021 13:00:24|NameReceived:|CountPrints:0|Staff_ID_Auxiliar:PES|PatientEpisode_ID:664831| 

ID:872474|Patient_ID:340246|Staff_ID:PFI|AppointmentDate:29/05/2021 09:33:21|Convencao:XCD_ttt_NE_C2|NBenef:3X34977|NRequisicao:4SFR09995393153409|NAutorization:|Treatment_ID:6898|TreatmentCode:743.9|TotalValue:75,34|PatientValue:0,00|ConvencaoValue:75,34|StaffValue:0,00|FactConvencao:True|FactConvencaoDate:31/05/2021 19:14:53|FactStaff:False|FactStaffGuID:|PatientValueDiscount:0,00|Recibo:True|ReciboGuID:|FactConvencaoClinic_ID:HJUSD2|Piece:|ClinicsLocations_ID:1|FactConvencaoYearMonth:202105|FactConvencaoSequencial:31|FactConvencaoLote:155|FactConvencaoStaff_ID:TRI|Quantity:1|FactConvencaoLoteType:M|RequesterCode_Medico:M2XD33|RequesterCode_CentroSaude:XCD202|PatientDiary_ID:F45724|Appointment_ID:793049|DataExecucao:29/05/2021 09:30:00|DataEntrega:04/06/2021 00:00:00|PatientEpisode_ID:664807|ToExecute:True|Position:1|FactConvencaoNDevolucao:|FactConvencaoCanDefact:|NRequisicaoDate:|DataFacturacao:29/05/2021 09:33:21|ClinicalReportsDestinations_ID:|ClinicalReportsDestinations_ByWho:|ClinicalReportsDestinations_Date:|ClinicalReportsDestinations_DateDelivery:|TypeOrigem:|SPMS_IdMcdt:|
```

Each of the strings between '|' and ':' is a column name for another table, with its value after the ':'. The data type is '`text`'.

I need to split those values into separate columns to update the other table.

Thanks.